# Configurations of minimal vectors for a 4-dimensional symplectic lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, sg.symplectic-geometry, euclidean-lattices, geometry-of-numbers

The possible configurations of minimal vectors for a 4-dimensional lattice are known for ages, but what about symplectic lattices ? If a 4-dimensional symplectic lattice $\Lambda$  has two minimal vectors $u,u'$, we know by Cauchy-Schwarz that $w(u,u')=0$ or $\pm 1$ where $w$ is the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{R}^4$. If $w(u,u')=1$ we know we can complete them into a symplectic basis of $\Lambda$, so there is one minimal class modulo $Sp(4,\mathbb{Z})$ of symplectic lattices with only two non-isotropic minimal vectors.

If we have three non-coplanar minimal vectors $(u,u',u'')$, we cannot have $w(u,u')=w(u,u'')=w(u',u'')=0$ because there is no 3-dimensional totally isotropic subspace in $\mathbb{R}^4$, but can we have $w(u,u')=w(u,u'')=1$ and $w(u',u'')=0$, or the three equal to 1 ?

More generally, do we have a classification of the minimal classes modulo $Sp(4,\mathbb{Z})$ ?